# Diagonal line in table cell is not placed correctly with vertical text

Tags: tables, rotating, height, diagbox

I want to have a diagonal line from the top left hand corner to the bottom right hand corner of the first cell of my table.

So I want it to look something like the left table:

[image]

By just plainly using `\diagbox` or `\backslashbox` the diagonal line does however not go through the entire cell. And it only looks like the table under "basic".

If I attempt to correct this by using the `height` option the height of the complete row is changed and I don't know how to avoid that.

Now of course I am not the first one to ask such a question. But the answers to similar questions like

> Diagonal line in table with vertical text

or

> Diagonal line in table header when header is tall

one just produce the same problem as setting the height.

Here is my code as a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

    % basic table
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        R\textbackslash PF & 
        \begin{turn}{-90}PF 333 \space\end{turn} \\
        \hline
        R1 \\
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{1cm}

    % simple diagonal line
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \diagbox{R}{PF} &
        %\backslashbox{R}{PF} &
        \begin{turn}{-90}PF 333 \space\end{turn} \\
        \hline
        R1 \\
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{1cm}

    % using height option
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \diagbox[height=3cm]{R}{PF} &
        \begin{turn}{-90}PF 333 \space\end{turn} \\
        \hline
        R1 \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I would be very glad if someone knew and would let me know how to fix this.
(sorry about the strange image and absent links but I do not have the reputation to post more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% using height option
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \diagbox[height=8ex, width=4em]{\raisebox{0.5\height}{\enspace R}}{ \raisebox{-0.8\height}{\ PF}} &
  \rotatebox[origin =c]{-90}{\,PF 333} \\
  \hline
  R1 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! While for me it does not matter whether I use `turn` or `\rotatebox` is there some (general) advantage to using `\rotatebox` ?

Comment: With `\rotatebox` you can specify the centre of rotation.

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\diagbox` which will alway draw a true diagonal line (because that drawn by using TikZ under the hood after the construction of the array).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines]
\diagbox{R}{PF} & \rotate PF 333\,\\
R1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip

\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{12mm}c}[hvlines]
\diagbox{R}{PF} & \rotate PF 333\,\\
R1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]